# Почему ++i считается lvalue, а i++ rvalue?

Tags: c++

Почему `++i` считается lvalue, а `i++` rvalue?
Я нашел ответ на данный вопрос на [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371503/why-is-i-considered-an-l-value-but-i-is-not), но мой ужасный английский не позволяет мне грамотно в этом разобраться. Ведь приоритет префиксного и постфиксного `++` всё равно выше, чем `&` и по идее в любом случае будет сначала `++`, а только потом `&` или я вообще не так понимаю?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Потому что после выполнения выражений:

```
i = 0;
(1) x = ++i;
(2) x = i++;
В x будут следующие значения:
(1) x = 1;
    i = 1;
(2) x = 0;
    i = 1;
```

Все эффекты связаны как раз с таким делением.

То есть `++i` означает увеличить `i` на один и взять *его* для выражения, а  `i++` означает взять *значение* `i` для выражения и после увеличить `i` на `1`.

Comment: IonRod вы путаете понятия префикс/постфикст с семантикой назначения, а это две разные вещи!

Comment: @perfect, вроде нет?

Answer (score 11):

Возможно, это очень неполный ответ по сравнению с развёрнутым первым по ссылке, но суть такая:

Постфиксный оператор меняет значение и возвращает только временную копию этого значения, которая, как следствие, не может быть изменена. То есть эта копия идёт отдельно от самого значения `i`, и может быть использована в выражении, но присваивание к `i++` не имеет смысла, т.к. результат `i++` сохраняется в какой-то другой ячейке памяти, не в той, где лежит `i`.

Результат `++i` записывается в неё же, поэтому выражение `++i = ...` имеет смысл (l-value).

Comment: На самом деле `++i` должен возвращать значение, и `++i =` смысла не иметь<br>
P.S. - оператор меняет переменную, а возвращает значение

Comment: В C++ `++i = x;` компилится и работает. Возвращает, но не во временную копию.

Comment: ++i как раз работает по ссылке на переменную, поэтому выполняется выстрее, чем i++, которое возвращает значени.

Comment: В таком случае, из-за приоритетов операции:

 i = 0;
 x = (++i + ++i );

При возврате ссылки, `x = 4`;<br>
При возврате значения, `x=3`;

Comment: >x = x++; // переменная вообще не меняется

 По-моему тут зависит от компилятора. Может поменяться, а может и нет.

Comment: Спасибо, только что проверил, в C++ (g++) действительно поменяется. В Java вот только никогда не меняется, я удалил это из ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Век живи, век учись. Взял и попробовал обсуждаемые варианты.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main ()
{
  int i = 0, x;

  x = (++i + ++i);
  printf ("i = 0; x = (++i + ++i): x=%d i=%d\n",x,i);
  i = 0;
  x = (i++ + i++);
  printf ("i = 0; x = (i++ + i++): x=%d i=%d\n",x,i);
  x = x++;
  printf ("x = x++: x=%d i=%d\n",x,i);
#ifdef __cplusplus
  ++i = x;
  printf ("++i = x: x=%d i=%d\n",x,i);
#endif
}

c:/Users/avp/src/cc/tst $ gcc t.c
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/tst $ ./a
i = 0; x = (++i + ++i): x=4 i=2
i = 0; x = (i++ + i++): x=0 i=2
x = x++: x=0 i=2
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/tst $ g++ t.c
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/tst $ ./a
i = 0; x = (++i + ++i): x=4 i=2
i = 0; x = (i++ + i++): x=0 i=2
x = x++: x=0 i=2
++i = x: x=0 i=0
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/tst $ g++ --version
g++.exe (GCC) 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

c:/Users/avp/src/cc/tst $ gcc --version
gcc.exe (GCC) 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

c:/Users/avp/src/cc/tst $ 
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/tst $
```

Comment: простите, что спрашиваю, но вы что использовали shell-код для windows?

Answer (score 2):

> Почему ++i считается lvalue, а i++ rvalue?

Потому что эти операторы так объявлены в соответствии со стандартом:

1. Прединкремент возвращает *ссылку*. Ссылке можно присвоить значение, а потому она *lvalue* («left side value», величина слева от знака равенства).
2. Постинкремент возвращает *значение*. Значению ничего присвоить нельзя; его самого присваивают, а потому оно *rvalue* («right side value», величина справа от знака равенства).

Answer (score 2):

Оператор `i++` никак не может возвращать lvalue по той простой причине, что нигде не существует подходящего lvalue для возвращения.

Постфиксный оператор `++` обязан возвращать *старое* значение своего операнда. Однако когда побочные эффекты постфиксного `++` возымели свое действие, его операнд уже поменял свое значение на новое, а старое значения операнда больше нигде в памяти не хранится. Т.е. возвращаемое lvalue просто некуда "привязывать" в памяти. Единственными способами возвращения старого значения является либо запоминание этого старого значения во временном объекте, либо его вычисление "на лету" из нового значения. В обоих случаях старое значение не будет lvalue.

Ситуация с префиксным оператором - обратная. Префиксный оператор должен возвращать *новое* значение своего операнда. Именно это новое значение операнд и будет содержать после реализации побочных эффектов префиксного `++`. Поэтому операнд префиксного оператора как раз и является тем самым lvalue которое оператор сразу и вернет.

Answer (score -2):

```
i++;                          /*называется постфиксной записью, в которой приоритет
                                операции низкий*/
++i;                          /*называется префиксной записью, в которой
                                приоритет операции высокий*/
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int i = 5;
int x = i++;                  /*здесь x == 5, а i == 6*/
int x = ++i;                  /*здесь x == 6, i == 6*/
```

Comment: А какой смысл-то в данном ответе?)